# '"/node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, npx, npm-package

I follow a Typescript and React course, where I built a CLI and I published it successfully on npmjs.com

But when I run the command "npx capycenta-app serve" (capycenta-app is the name of the package I just published) I get this message:

'"/node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command ... " It's strange to see those quotes and the bar in front of "node", does anyone experienced the same issues? I declared node and npm as global variables in my system.